# What can I do to separate users best way if they are allowed to run their ruby (python) code

Tags: linux, access-control, account-security

I have Ubuntu server 12.04 on VDS and I allow users to run their own Rails applications on behalf their own accounts. That means:

1. They can use any shell they want
2. They can upload what they want, e.g. .so libs
3. They can call any function from any .so lib they uploaded

What can I do to separate them as much as possible and to save my server from being taken under control in such circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your best bet would be to have each user on a virtualized environment where you can sandbox their activities. That is assuming your server can handle the additional load.

Comment: I agree with you. But can you direct me to certain sandbox suitable for using on VDS?

I thought about Linux vServer, but AFAIK it requires dedicated server to function, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, i have no personal experience with VDS, you might want to wait for other users answers.